# Using a Batch File to edit the Windows Registry when the Reg Key has spaces

Tags: registry

I have a registry key I want to modify in a batch file.  The name of the key is "FormSuggest Passwords"

When I run the batch file (which has many other working lines), I get an error "Invalid Key Name"

Here is the line itself.

reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\MicrosoftEdge\Main\ /v 'FormSuggest Passwords' /t REG_SZ /d yes

Aside from scouring the internet, I've tried double quotation marks, single quotation marks, etc. with no change.